# How to disable scroll of the whole page using pointer events on an element?

Tags: javascript, browser, scroll, pointer-events

I've got an library that allows drawing on a canvas. Currently, it supports mouse and touch events. I'd like to add support for pointer events as well.

I'm handling `pointerdown`, `pointermove` and `pointerup` events on the canvas element. Everything works fine in Chrome on my laptop when I use mouse. However, when I try it out on my tablet, I'm only getting a few `pointermove` events (2-5) before getting `pointercancel` event followed by `pointerout` and `pointerleave`.

I guess the browser is triggering `pointercancel`, because moving my finger over the canvas triggers scrolling of the whole page as well.

To disable scrolling when using touch events, I'm calling `event.preventDefault()` in handlers for `touchstart` and `touchmove` events, but this solution doesn't seem to be working with pointer events.

How to disable scrolling of the whole page when I draw over the canvas element when using pointer events?

Comment: Have you tried `.stopPropagation()` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried the CSS property `touch-action: none`? It disables any kind of user-agent behavior (like scrolling) on an element.

For more fine grained options checkout the MDN article for [touch-action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action).

Comment: Thanks! I'm setting it when browser is using touch events, but completely forgot about it and I didn't set it up for pointer events.

Comment: What if I want to disable scrolling conditionally, e.g. when a specific place is tapped?